# Problems plotting intraday OHLC data in R with quantmod chartSeries

Tags: r, plot, quantmod

I have an xts/zoo object ESZ1:

```
> class(ESZ1) 
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

with

```
> class(time(ESZ1))
[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXct"
```

and

```
> colnames(ESZ1)
[1] "ESZ1.Open"    "ESZ1.High"    "ESZ1.Low"     "ESZ1.Close"   "ESZ1.Volume"  "ESZ1.WAP"     "ESZ1.hasGaps" "ESZ1.Count"
```

and I would like to plot it using the chartSeries function from the package quantmod. However, I get the following error:

```
> chartSeries(ESZ1)
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any ideas of what the problem could be would be greatly appreciated.

Additional question: 
Is there any documentation for how to adjust the axes/margins for chartSeries()? Currently my y-axis labels are partially cut off on the right-hand margin of the plot. I've tried using

```
mar = ...
```

in the argument list of chartSeries, but this did not change the resulting plot.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276).

Comment: Sorry about that - see comments below.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is within chartSeries, specifically the axTicksByTime call.  I'll add a patch to fix this, but for now you can do:

```
chartSeries(ESZ1, major.ticks="minutes")
```

By default **major.ticks="auto"** and it seems to fail too early in the automagical procedure to get to the right answer.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Note that it's March 2013 and I'm using the latest versions. Maybe the origin of my problem is different? I have daily data, but major.ticks="minutes" helped, despite the absence of minutes data. I don't have the problem for a truncated version of the same dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided enough information about your `ESZ1` object, but I can reproduce the error by trying to plot 2 minutes or less of data.  Your column names look like something from IBrokers,so ...

```
> library(IBrokers)
> library(quantmod)
> ibg <- ibgConnect()
> fut <- twsFUT('ES', 'GLOBEX', '201112')
> ESZ1 <- reqHistoricalData(ibg, fut, barSize='1 secs', duration='120 S')
TWS Message: 2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture 
TWS Message: 2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds2a 
waiting for TWS reply on ES .... done.
> chartSeries(ESZ1)
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

If you use more than 2 minutes of data it works.

```
> ESZ1 <- reqHistoricalData(ibg, fut, barSize='1 secs', duration='121 S')
waiting for TWS reply on ES .... done.
> chartSeries(ESZ1)

> indexClass(ESZ1)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> colnames(ESZ1)
[1] "ESZ1.Open"    "ESZ1.High"    "ESZ1.Low"     "ESZ1.Close"   "ESZ1.Volume" 
[6] "ESZ1.WAP"     "ESZ1.hasGaps" "ESZ1.Count"
```

Comment: My apologies for not providing a reproducible example, but yes, you correctly gathered that I was using IBrokers to import data. And yes, I was trying to plot only 1 minute of data consisting of 1-second bars. Is that not possible? I'll try and see if it will work for me with more than 2 minutes of data.